What can I do about the gap in the glass 'door' of this cabinet?
See images and clip below.
We got a beautiful new display cabinet with sliding glass 'doors'.
But on one side the glass does 'set' properly against the frame when closed - the angle of the glass doesn't match the angle between the side of the cabinet and the runner of the 'door', so a big gap is left in the upper corner, when the bottom corner is flush up to the edge of the cabinet.
If I push firmly the glass panel rotates around the bottom right corner, to "fit" at the top right, by lifting up at the bottom left.
What can I do?

I can't see anyway to get the glass door out, so even if I could get someone to make a "correct" glass door, I don't see how I could put it in?

If I were to try to put a "shim" at the bottom left corner, I don't see how I'd attach it to the glass, so it didn't just come off when closing the 'door'.

I guess I could attach a shim to the side of the cabinet fill the gap, but that seems like it'd be pretty ugly.

Similarly I would expect any attempt to extend the glass panel itself would be incredibly ugly.

And I'm invested in closing the gap, because one of the reasons we wanted an enclosed cabinet, was to stop dust (and spiders, ew) from getting into all our glassware :(


The Gap (click for full image):

Despite being flush at the bottom (click for full image):

The whole cabinet (click for full image):

Film of "tipping it" to close: https://imgur.com/a/CwTNcCs

Measure from top right to bottom left.  Repeat for the opposite side.  This will tell if the cabinet is square.  Can be the glass is not cut square either.   Is this bought new, or just new to you?  If bought new can usually return it.

If it turns out not to be square (which will almost certainly be the case, pardon the pun) the woodworking stack would be the best place to ask for advice in pulling it back into squareness. This is a question about furnishing, not home improvement.
